# How can I uninstall the WeTransfer extension in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 68.4.1 (64-Bit) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Since 2019 it comes stock with 'FileLink for WeTransfer', which I deactived immediately but I'd like to get rid of it completely. Unfortunately there's no uninstall option in the addon GUI.
Is there a way to remove it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 16.04, this extension is in `/usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net.xpi`.

So you can delete it:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net.xpi
```

or just rename it:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net.xpi \
 /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net.xpi.off
```

However, note that it will be re-installed at the next Thunderbird upgrade. And since it is enabled by default on a fresh install, you may prefer to leave it alone and just disable it in the "Add-ons" page.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why there's no uninstall button for this extension? Is this hardcoded inside TB?

Comment: @lmoly : Yes, looks like it's now part of Thunderbird. See the announcements about that "partnership" on the [The Thunderbird Blog](https://blog.thunderbird.net/2019/05/wetransfer-file-transfer-now-available-in-thunderbird/) and on the [WeTransfer news](https://wetransfer.pr.co/172897-wetransfer-integrated-into-mozilla-s-thunderbird-email-client). But it's easy to remove anyway.

Comment: After removing the xpi file, thunderbird logs errors to syslog at
every launch. The first line contains the following:
#011addons.xpi-utils#011WARN#011addMetadata: Add-on wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net is invalid: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST) [nsIFile.isFile]"  nsresult: "0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm :: get :: line 235"  data: no] Stack trace: get()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm:235